# c# xaml performance of customisable viewcells

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin App which displays a whole lot of questions (e.g. like an exam)

```
public class Question {
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public string Settings {get;set;}
   public int Type_Id {get;set;}
   public string Additional_Info {get;set;}
}
```

These questions are contained in a list. They are displayed in ViewCells. They all display the "Text" at top, but the appearance can vary a lot beyond that:

- There are currently 20 different values for Type_Id. Each one
  displays a different body that enables you to answer the question (an
  Entry, a Datepicker, a button which opens up the camera and take a
  photo).
- You can add many different '[keys]' to Settings to change the
  appearance. e.g. if Settings.contains("[R]"), a red "required" star
  is displayed next to the question

The original implementation was entirely in c#. That is the code looked like this (simplified):

```
public class QuestionViewCell : StackLayout {
   public QuestionViewCell(Question q){
      Children.Add(new Label { Text=q.Text });

      //this might change background color, spacing, default font, etc.
      AddStuffFromSettings(q.Settings);      

      if (q.Type_Id == 1){
          Children.Add(new Entry());
      } else if (q.Type_Id ==2){
          //The question is answered by taking a picture
          AddCameraButton();
      }
   }
}
```

Then the cells would be added to the page as follows

```
List<Question> questions = database.GetQuestions();
foreach(Question q in questions){
    Children.Add(new QuestionViewCell());
}
```

This was fine, but has issues with maintainability and extensibility. So I've been trying to switch to MVVM xaml approach.

The implementation I've been trying uses this class in the place of if statements:
https://github.com/xDelivered-Patrick/Xamarin.Forms.Essentials/tree/master/Essentials/Controls/State

So the experimental implementation looks like this:

```
<cont:StateContainer State="{Binding QuestionItem.Type_Id}" IsVisible="{Binding IsContentVisible}">
   <cont:StateCondition Is="1">
       <Entry/>
   </cont:StateCondition>

   <cont:StateCondition Is="2">
       <Button Text="{Binding CameraButtonText}" Command="{Binding CameraButtonPressed}"/>
   </cont:StateCondition>
</cont:StateContainer>
```

I then use a whole lot of bindings to toggle the "IsVisible" property of a whole lot of elements that depend on the 'Question.Settings' property. Then I just set those properties in the ViewModel.

The issue is that this approach takes 2-3 times longer to open a page than the c# implementation.

The implementation I've been trying looks sketchy to me. But someone showed it to me and it's the only way I know how.

So I guess my questions are:

- Is there a way to convert to an MVVM approach for these ViewCells
  without taking a large performance hit?
- What is causing the large performance hit for this experimental implementation?

Comment: do you read this article from microsoft documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is a DataTemplateSelector, to decide what template you use for each ViewCell.

Don't forget to simplify your Layouts, and in the listview, set the `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`.

Here is the documentation https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/

Comment: Hey, datatemplateselector was the option I was most interested in. But I have a couple of issues with it. Because I've got 20 different type_Ids and ~10 different settings. That adds up to 200 different data templates (potentially I can get it down to 20-30 but it's still a lot of reused code).

I've tried RecycleElement but it seems to cause quite a few errors since the cells vary so much from cell to cell (also the UI feels a lot more clunky especially the size of the scrollbar changing).

Comment: You should rethink your Application Design then.  Mixing so much information within the same list, it's problably not a good option.